# Joins or includes with 2 foreign keys on one model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, include, foreign-keys

I have a membership app where a "Participant" has two foreign keys for a "Users" table, the actual member's id (user_id) and the id of the user who "added" the member (added_by) to a "Club".  I am trying to make a method where I list all of  the "Clubs" a given User(user_id) has been added to by another User(added_by). The text I'm trying to get is:

```
user.firstname (<-defined by user_id) has been added to Club.name by user.firstname (<-defined by added_by)

class ClubsController < ApplicationController

   @invites = Participant.find(current_user.id).includes(:user => foreign_key: :added_by).joins(:club)
```

Here are my models

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :participants
    belongs_to :user,  foreign_key: :added_by
    belongs_to :current_user

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :club
 has_many :users, through: :participants

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :participants,  foreign_key: :added_by
```

Comment: You're messing up the relation, you can't have the same relation name more than once, define clear names, for example, instead of using the actual class names use the logical application name for the relations, for example `user has_one :inviter`, `has_many :friends`, `belongs_to :trainer` even though all those could be just users at the end, rails will understand as long as you tell it that those are users.

Comment: I don't have the same relation name more than once.  the Model Participants has User_id and Added_by, I did not list user_id twice.  Are you says I should say Paricipant belongs_to :added_by?  How will rails know it belongs to User through :added_by?

Comment: you add an extra parameter called `class_name`, i said more than once because you said `belongs_to :user` twice and `has_many :participants` twice